# How do I hook up the authProvider in react-admin to use SAML?

Tags: react-admin, onelogin, passport-saml

I've tried following the sample code on the passport-saml site, and the advanced tutorial on the react-admin site for OAuth, but haven't been able to figure out what I need to do with the authProvider to get an authenticated session available in react-admin using SAML.

I can currently log into my app through OneLogin (clicking on the app in the panel) and write out the user's information (inside the passport.serializeUser function), so I know that piece is working, but I'm not sure how to get that information over to the authProvider.

The login function on authProvider is hit when you submit the form, so if I could replicate what OneLogin is sending over when I click on the app, I could probably make that call in authProvider.login and make a custom login page that submits on load rather than waiting for a submit, but that doesn't seem intentional.

What am I missing here, and is there a better option that I'm not considering?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a getUser function on the server and using the authProvider.login function to hit that endpoint, parse the user data off of the response, and store it in localStorage. Then logout removes the user from localStorage, and checkAuth just gets the user from localStorage.

This is working for my purposes at the moment, although eventually I will want to expire the users. Hope this helps anyone else trying to hook up OneLogin with React-admin.